# Security of AWS automated backup via snapshots

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, backup, snapshot

I need to automate backup of a Linux AWS instance. I would like to do this via one of the many scripts available that rely on the API access of AWS to do snapshots of the underlying EBS volume.

What I had trouble to find out is if I should run these scripts/enable API access on the instance to back up, on another instance, or even from a host from outside of AWS? What is safer?

[1] https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create an IAM user (or instance role, if you prefer) that can **only** create snapshots - nothing else, including deletion - and use that user's access keys, it pretty much won't matter.

Even if your keys leaked out to 4chan, the worst they could do would be to make a whole bunch of snapshots.

Here's an example IAM policy:

```
{
    "Statement": [{
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateSnapshot"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't know that I could limit what a user could do. Kinda obvious though.

Comment: IAM users and roles are very much your friend. :-)